# Export dynamic label text to Excel

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, excel, export-to-excel

I have a small program that generates a few dynamic labels in a `flowLayoutPanel1` I ma trying to export these labels' text to Excel but all I get is the value of the last label.

This is my Export class:

```
 class Export
    {

        public Export(bool defaultBackgroundIsWhite)
        {
            this.defaultBackgroundIsWhite = defaultBackgroundIsWhite;

            app = new Application();
            app.Visible = true;
            workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
            worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
        }

        public void Do(string excelName, System.Windows.Forms.Label names)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                    AddNames(i,0,names);
            }
        }

        private void AddNames(int row, int col, System.Windows.Forms.Label lbls)
        {
            if (lbls == null) return;
            row++;
            col++;
            Range range = worksheet.Cells[row + 2, col + 2];
            range.NumberFormat = "";
            worksheet.Cells[row + 2, col + 2] = lbls.Text;
            row--;
            col--;

        }
        private Application app = null;
        private Workbook workbook = null;
        private Worksheet worksheet = null;
        private bool defaultBackgroundIsWhite;
    }
```

The form class code:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        create();
    }

    Label lbl;
    private void create()
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
        //int length = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Name = i.ToString();
            lbl.Text = "Label "+i;
            lbl.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 10, FontStyle.Regular);
            lbl.SetBounds(0, 20, 100, 25);
            lbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Export ep = new Export(true);
        ep.Do("test.xsl", lbl);
    }
```

My Results:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Label> lbls = new List<Label>();
private void create()
{
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
    //int length = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Name = i.ToString();
        lbl.Text = "Label "+i;
        lbl.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 10, FontStyle.Regular);
        lbl.SetBounds(0, 20, 100, 25);
        lbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        lbls.Add(lbl);   //< -- add the label to the local list of Labels
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lbl);

    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    Export ep = new Export(true);
    foreach(var lbl in lbls)
    {
        i++;
        ep.AddNames(i,0,lbl);
    }
}
```

---

```
public void AddNames(int row, int col, System.Windows.Forms.Label lbl)
{
if (lbl == null) return;
row++;
col++;
Range range = worksheet.Cells[row + 2, col + 2];
range.NumberFormat = "";
worksheet.Cells[row + 2, col + 2] = lbl.Text;
row--;
col--;

}
```

Comment: See the OP's comment, that's what matters, he got the message and now he knows and hopefully he'll never make the same mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You are always adding the text of the last created label because you are only passing its reference. You should instead pass the List with references of all the labels which Text properties you would like to export to Excel. Change these methods:

```
    List<Label> lbls;
    private void create()
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
        //int length = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        lbls = new List<Labels>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Name = i.ToString();
            lbl.Text = "Label "+i;
            lbl.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 10, FontStyle.Regular);
            lbl.SetBounds(0, 20, 100, 25);
            lbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
            lbls.Add(lbl);
        }
    }
```

Also change the method `Do` in the `Export` class to accept the `List<Label>` instead `Label`:

```
    public void Do(string excelName, List<Label> names)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= names.Count; i++)
        {
                AddNames(i,0,names[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're constructing a new label every time around the for loop in the create() method, and assigning that label to the same field (lbl).  By the time you're done, lbl is the last label you created.  You could instead add the labels to a List, or pass flowLayoutPanel1.Controls to the go() method, if you can be certain that will contain only the labels you wish to export.

It's a bit clunky TBH, and depending so heavily on the mechanics of the UI like that is not recommended - you'd be far better of with a well thought out model to which your UI is data bound, but if you want to just get it done, that's your problem.

Comment: How do you bind data in Excel to a Object Model in VSTO or a Winform?

Comment: I was thinking more that you'd bind your UI to your model, and query the model to do your Excel stuff...

Comment: +1 for sportsmanship, you are right, looks like OP is after a quick and dirty solution, Nikola & I oblige:)

Comment: ... and you're both quick off the mark with working code! I just can't help but pass comment on these things sometimes.

Comment: Well, when I see the code like this (clearly beginners code) I generally try to make changes to the code in such a way that OP can figure it out how the code he is coding could be corrected. If I start to give general recommendations I think that it will only discourage him to continue with learning (trying). Through time OP will be able to write better code and thus correct the previous one. And by saying this I, by no means, think that coding directions shouldn't be given here, only that I (based on my working experience) think that, while learning, programmer can't learn everything at once.

Comment: Wise words, and I agree. Like I said, can't help myself sometimes.